# How to access a specific data in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I found the python script below and made some improvements however, there is something I cant manage to work. I had been struggling to find the needed resource.

```
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase

NUM_questionFileS_PER_studFileUIZ = 5
questionFileS = {
    "This is question A":
    ["Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3",], "This is question B": ["Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3",],
}

num_questionFiles = min(NUM_questionFileS_PER_studFileUIZ, len(questionFileS))
questionFiles = random.sample(list(questionFileS.items()), k=num_questionFiles)

num_correct = 0
for num, (questionFile, alternatives) in enumerate(questionFiles, start=1):
    print(f"\nQuestion {num}:")
    print(f"{questionFile}?")
    
    correct_answer = alternatives[0]
    labeled_alternatives = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, random.sample(alternatives, k=len(alternatives))))
    for label, alternative in labeled_alternatives.items():
        print(f"  {label}) {alternative}")

    while (answer_label := input("\nYour Choice? ")) not in labeled_alternatives:
        print(f"Please answer one of {', '.join(labeled_alternatives)}")
  
    answer = labeled_alternatives[answer_label] 
    
    if answer == correct_answer:
        num_correct += 1
        print("That is correct!")
    else:
        print(f"Wrong Answer  :   {label} {answer!r}")
        print(f"Correct Answer:   {label} {correct_answer!r}")
```

Sample Output:

```
Question 2:
This is question A?
  a) Choice 1
  b) Choice 2
  c) Choice 3

Your Choice? b    # This is the part I needed help
Wrong Answer  :   c 'Choice 2'
Correct Answer:   c 'Choice 1'
```

Wanted Output:

```
Your Choice? b    
Wrong Answer  :   b) Choice 2
Correct Answer:   a) Choice 1
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `labeled_alternatives[answer_label]`? That's doing what you asked

Comment: Note - you're printing `label` on both the correct and incorrect answer. One of those should be `answer_label`

Comment: I wanted to print the choice like a) b) c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label` is always the last element from the original list and shouldn't be reused

```
print(f"Wrong Answer  :  {answer_label}) {answer!r}") 
print(f"Correct Answer:  {list(labeled_alternatives.keys())[0]}) {correct_answer!r}")
```

Comment: Getting `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Got it working but still have some problems. Im trying to figure it out.